# libxslt is missing installing Nokogiri with RVM

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

It's been one month I'm trying to install the Nokogiri gem on Fedora 16 to run a friend's Rails project.

I installed Ruby with RVM. Using `gem install nokogiri` returns

```
libxslt is missing. please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
```

So I tried installing `libxslt-devel` with `yum` and it didn't work. So I used `rvm reinstall` to recompile ruby with xslt path given and it still doesn't work.

Then I tried installing `ruby-xslt` but it doesn't work because I'm using RVM.

How do I solve this awkward problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install appropriate RVM package.

```
rvm pkg install libxslt
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work.